# How to pass localStorage in PHPMailer?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

I have a `form`, I send data from it to the mail, using PHPMailer. Also, I have a list of products that I retrieve from `localStorage`. How can I transfer an array of data from the localStorage to PHPMailer to send to the mail?

```
       if (ajax) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            const formAction = form.getAttribute('action') ? form.getAttribute('action').trim() : '#';
            const formMethod = form.getAttribute('method') ? form.getAttribute('method').trim() : 'GET';
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            
            form.classList.add('_sending');
            const response = await fetch(formAction, {
                method: formMethod,
                body: {
                    'formData': formData
                }
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                let responseResult = await response.json();
                form.classList.remove('_sending');
                formSent(form);
            } else {
                alert("Error");
                form.classList.remove('_sending');
            }
        }
```

Example of a product in `localStorage`[image]

```
<div data-id="1" class="product">
    <div class="product__name">Name</div>
    <div class="product__price">320</div>
    <div class="product__weigh">100</div>
</div>
```

```
<?php

$body = '<h1>Новий заказ!</h1>';

$name = '<strong>' . $_POST['name'] . '</strong>'; 
$surname = '<strong>' . $_POST['surname'] . '</strong>';  
$phone = '<strong>' . $_POST['phone'] . '</strong>'; 


$body .= 
'Name: ' . $name . '<br>' .
'Surname: ' . $surname . '<br>' .
'Phone: ' . $phone . '<br>' .


$mail->Body = $body;

if (!$mail->send()) {
    $message = 'Error';
} else {
    $message = 'Success!';
}

$response = ['message' => $message];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

Comment: what data from localStorage do you want to send?

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto I updated the code. I have an HTML of the product. I need to collect information from it (product name, price, etc.) and send it to the mail. And so for each product

Comment: For clarity's sake, do you want to add data from localStoraga to your current formData-object (then just google "add values to formData" or similar), or do you want to make a different request will only data from localStorage? Also, this doesn't have anything to do with PHP or PHPMailer. The question is about JS. In PHP, you would just get the data, just like the form data.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I do not care how to add them, one request will be more convenient. My main thing is to get it and send it to the email

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thanks for the answer. After that, how do you get the value in PHP? $_POST('example-value') doesn't work

Comment: _"I do not care how to add them, one request will be more convenient"_ - Well, _we_ care since we don't want to assume things and waste time writing incorrect answers. If the data from localStorage should be in the same email as the data from the form, then you don't really have many options (unless you want to write a lot of unnecessary code), you need to send it together with the form. What have you actually tried!?

Comment: It's `$_POST['theName']` not `$_POST('theName')`. It's an array, not function. You will get them just like you would get any other data from the form. I can't give you the _exact_ code since I don't know how you add them to the request.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Yes, I need to send it along with the form. I get the first name, last name, phone number. Now I need to get the entire list of ordered products that are stored localStorage. Put it all together in a pile and send it to the mail. inputs I get with $_POST(['input']). But I don't know how to get products from the local storage

Comment: @M.Eriksson I added the PHP code

Comment: Why are you storing product information in localStorage to begin with? Remember that the users can easily modify _all_ info in localStorage (like the price) so I hope you don't depend on the price you get from it. Usually, the front end only remember product id's. Then you can pass those id's to the backend and query your DB for the correct data about them.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I'm still learning, you could consider it a learning project. I don't have a database

Comment: So did you manage to add the data to the request? How you did that will determine how to access it in PHP so you will need to show it. Also, you can always just do `var_dump($_POST);` in PHP to see what it contains, and to give you a hint on how to fetch the data.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I tried this with myForm.append('example-value', 'value'). I don't understand how to get this value in PHP now. $_POST() - doesn't work

Comment: @M.Eriksson Maybe I made a mistake, I'll check now.

Comment: @M.Eriksson It worked. Sorry, I'm dumb. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Concepts

`localStorage` is your browser's local storage. By its nature, it is defined only in your browser.

PHPMailer (and, as a matter of fact anything PHP-related) runs on your server.

Your browser and your server are at least two separate applications, but in prod environments they are also separate, remote machines that cannot trivially refer to each-other.

So, your PHP code cannot reach your `localStorage`. Instead, it can only communicate with it.

## localStorage

This is a key-value pair resource mapped to a certain webplace, in this case, your website. If you do not know the keys, then you can retrieve them via

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
```

You can also `map` your products into key-value pairs like this:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).map((key) => ({key, value: localStorage.getItem(key)}))
```

You may have other items in the `localStorage` that you might not want to send, in which case you may need to add some further filtering, but the above is the bulk of the logic that you need.

## Appending your products to FormData

You can use the [.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) function for that purpose:

```
formData.append(someKey, someValue)
```

or, to apply your mapping:

```
formData.append("products", Object.keys(localStorage).map((key) => ({key, value: localStorage.getItem(key)})));
```

## Sending the FormData

Since you already successfully submitting your data, I do not delve into this aspect too deeply, but it's worth mentioning that if you have a custom `FormData`, then you will need to submit it programmatically, via Javascript, by a call to `fetch` in your case.

## Receiving your data

You will need to look into `$_POST` for the `products` key and you will see what the values are and process them into your mail.